# How to sum positive cases by date in python

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, sum, numeric

I am new in coding and I work with positive COVID cases. I have a DataFrame with all the positive (e.g **case 1 : positive : 2020-04-30**) and I have to make the sum of positive cases per day in a numeric way (i.g **3 positive cases : 2020-04-30**) in order to create a plot, but I don't know how can I do his with python, I know that I have to use the function `groupby()` and `sum ()` but I don't know how, can you help me please ?

Thank you !

[Here is a table which represent my DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MhER.png)

[Here is a table of what I want to have as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0luRM.png)

My actual data are confidential but I give you a sample of them [my actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNm66.png)

Comment: Did you look up the documentation for those functions? Please do that, then make an attempt and provide a [mre] to explain the specific issue with your attempt. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should aggregate by column and then sum the results, try this:

Notice that, the patient name should should have a numerical counter for keeping track.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

# this a dummy set, you should have already this in your data frame
dict_df = {'Patient': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Positive': ['Positive'] * 5, 'Date': [datetime.date(2020, 4, 21), datetime.date(2020, 4, 22), datetime.date(2020, 4, 21), datetime.date(2020, 4, 23), datetime.date(2020, 4, 22)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_df)

# create a numerics counter
cases = df['Positive'].to_numpy()
counter = np.where(cases == 'Positive', 1, 0)

# add column to data frame
df['counter'] = counter

# use groupby and sum
results = df['counter'].groupby(df['Date']).sum()
print(results)

#Results
#Date            Cases             
#2020-04-21        2
#2020-04-22        2
#2020-04-23        1
```

Comment: @DD3 If this comment was helpful and you consider it as correct, please mark it as such. Greetings, MBV.

Comment: It doesn't because I have a big Data Frame of 1880 rows and 12 columns, I just give you here an example to simplify the explication, thank you for trying helping me

Comment: could you provide the actual data? because this seems simple enough to do. In SO you should always put a working exmaple for people so it is easier for them to help you. Just a sample data. Let me try to get you from the data you posted to the answer you want.

Comment: @DD3 The answer is edited, I it is exactly what you request, please have a look at it.

Comment: I put in the description a sample of my actual data, sorry I am a beginner in programming word I am learning step by step

Comment: Don't worry. first, you should attempt to do it yourself and post the error or incorrect behavior. Second, a working example is encouraged for debugging. Third, rarely anyone will create data from a picture to make some test on some random code, you need to provide usable data. Finally, in So is very appreciated when the OP shows effort and does previous research on the question show, please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Concerning the 'actual data you provided, you could use the same code I wrote as an answer an put it under a for loop for every 'Visit' column. Hope it helps.